# Sukuli Button recognition while doing RDP

Tags: java, windows, winapi

I am new to Sukuli world and and was looking for some creative solution.
Issue - I am working on a project to do RDP for 5000 users. There is a disclosure button which comes once login. I need to find a way to click on OK button using java technology. I used sukuli and initialized X,Y corrdinates(OK Button) and doing a click after 10 sec from doing RDP. Now issue is i have to know as soon as OK button is created on screen to click on it effectively and remove the wait period of 10 seconds. Also the code will be error prone if the OK button is created after more than 10 sec.

Is it possible using sukuli or from any other technology?

Answer (score 1):

You can register to be notified when an object is created. [WinEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) provides the infrastructure for this. In your callback you can filter out the object you are interested in. Once found you can retrieve an [`IAccessible` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318466.aspx) and perform the desired action on it, for example [`IAccessible::accDoDefaultAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318470.aspx).